# Authenticating user groups with PAM in C

Tags: c, pam, authentication

I am writing a program that allow certain users and user groups to **not** require authentication through PAM. I want to use the **pam_access** module but am fairly new and can't find good documentation for beginners.

How do I link in the .so file for pam_access and use it to verify a user or a specific user group in C?